# TypeError: sequence index must be integer

Tags: range, python-2.5

I just have a problem with adding between every 3 characters a ",".

```
print totalpoints
points = ','.join([totalpoints[i:i+3] for i in range(0, totalpoints, 3)])
```

Output:

```
875
TypeError: sequence index must be integer
```

Comment: can you elaborate? what is `totalpoints`? If it is not a string /list, how do you suppose you would use `slice`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you are actually trying to do. But If I am not wrong, following will solve your problem.

```
>>> totalpoints = 875123123 
>>> totalpoints = str(totalpoints)
>>> points = ','.join([totalpoints[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(totalpoints), 3)])
>>> points
'875,123,123'
```

Comment: how about a small elaboration of what was the error, or minimal what you changed?